# WordPress multilanguage text using code with PolyLang

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual

I'm creating my multilanguage WordPress website using polylang plugin and Loco translate, but nothing happens with few lines. First "Product has been added to your cart", second is in checkout page "checkout" button,.

Maybe code exist with which I can replace this text In few languages?

I have in mind something like that

```
If ($lang = 'gb') {
Product has been added to your cart } else {
Other language text goes here }
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience with polylang, but you could probably achieve this by using polylang `pll_current_language()` function, like this:

```
if (pll_current_language() == 'en') {
  echo "Product has been added to your cart";
} else if (pll_current_language() == 'de') {
  echo "Text in german";
}
```

Comment: Try to add "echo pll_current_language()" to see what values this function returns for each language you use and then use those values in above code.

Comment: thanks for help, both my languages returned same value, now I just changed options in polylang settings and now It's okay. Thanks man!

Comment: I'm glad it works. If you have found this answer helpful, consider accepting it by clicking on a checkbox . Thank you.